# Calculate percentage share within rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with various states GDP data divided in multiple sectors. I am trying to get the percentage contribution of primary, secondary and tertiary sectors as a percentage of total GDP for all the states.
Below is the dataframe and I am not sure how I can approach towards this. [image: DataFrame]

Below are the results I am trying to achieve:

```
Primary % Contribution = (Primary for that state/ State GSDP )* 100 
Secondary % Contribution = (Secondary for that state/ State GSDP )* 100 
Tertiary % Contribution = (Tertiary for that state/ State GSDP )* 100
```

I am trying to get an output of this as below.

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question. Where does the `tertiary` data lie and the row labelled for `Gross State Domestic Product` is then the total for that state right? I think I misunderstood it first time around

Comment: My bad, the initial states data does not have tertiary rows.

Comment: So it's `primary/gross state`?

Comment: yes, we need to calculate primary/GrossState, secondary/GrossState and tertiary/GrossState percentages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pivot` the dataframe:

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='State',columns='Item', values='GSDP')
for item in ['Primary', 'Secondary']:
    new_df[item+'_pct'] = new_df[item]/new_df['Gross State'] 

new_df['Tertiary_pct'] = 1 - new_df[['Primary_pct', 'Secondary_pct']].sum(1)
```

Note: `pivot` works only if you have one row for each pair `(state, item)`. Otherwise, consider `pivot_table`:

```
new_df = df.pivot_table(index='State',columns='Item', values='GSDP', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: We cannot use 'State' as index because there are duplicates for that data.

Comment: I got that error before passing `values='GSDP'` to `pivot`. Please check.

Comment: Yes I did. This is what I get : "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" when I pivot the dataframe as you mentioned.

Comment: Try this: `df.groupby(['State', 'Item']).count().eq(1).all()` if you see any `False`. If yes, you need to double check you data for duplication. If no, i'm lost :-).

Comment: What does this do? Does this mean the data has duplicates in these two columns? I am getting false for two of them. (index - False, GSDP-False)

Comment: that checks if you have duplicate items in pairs: `['State', 'Item']`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: My bad, the data has duplicates. Let me remove and try again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution will pivot by the `state` column and then you have all of the information to calculate the percentages.

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='state', columns='item', values='GSDP')
```

Now you can easily calculate your percentages:

```
df_pivot['PrimaryPercent'] = df_pivot.Primary / df_pivot['Gross State Domestic Product'] * 100
df_pivot['SecondaryPercent'] = df_pivot.Secondary / df_pivot['Gross State Domestic Product'] * 100
```

etc